# Running qemu on ARM with KVM acceleration

Tags: arm, virtualization, qemu, kvm

I'm trying to emulate an ARM VM on an ARM host, a [cubieboard2](http://cubieboard.org/model/) embedded board, by means of `qemu`. I've compiled `qemu` from the source code and enabled `kvm`. Now the problem is that launching `qemu-system-arm` as follows:

```
$ /usr/local/bin/qemu-system-arm -M accel=kvm -cpu host -kernel vmlinuz-3.2.0-4-vexpress -initrd initrd.img-3.2.0-4-vexpress -sd debian_wheezy-_armhf_standard.qcow2 -append "console=ttyAMA0 root=/dev/mmcblk0p2" -nographic
```

I have this error:

```
qemu-system-arm: -M accel=kvm: Unsupported machine type
Use -machine help to list supported machines!
```

What is wrong in the command I've typed. How to enable `kvm`?

Answer (score 1):

How about reading this:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/cubieboard/4EGONZMoIAU

And yes, you are right, as the Cubieboard2 has A15, HYP hypervisor is implemented and KVM should be running in it.

More about HYP mode is covered here:

http://lwn.net/Articles/557132/

there is another way you can see the failing mode (why qemu command failed): execute your command under "strace", and you will be able to clearly see when /dev/kvm is opened, and if it succeed, non-zero fd will be returned after open("/dev/kvm") is called. and before all this - "lsmod" should return a line indicating "kvm.ko" kernel module is running, and if you can read your kernel's config file, there should be a "CONFIG_KVM" embedded within.

Comment: What do you mean with «KVM does not exist on ARM»? Some ARM CPUs have HYP mode and KVM uses this mode to enable the virtualization. Anyway I get the same error even if I specify the architecture. The issue is the parameter to activate kvm acceleration.

Answer (score 1):

-M takes a machine name (eg "vexpress-a15" or "virt"), not a set of suboption=value settings. You want -machine suboption=value,... for that.

("-M name" is a shortcut for "-machine type=name".)

You also need to specify a machine name, either via -machine type=name or -M name, otherwise QEMU will complain that you didn't specify one.